# Simple Powershell where filter not working

Tags: powershell

Dears,

Executing the below powershell command returns no value even though it should return some matched values. Am i missing something?

```
 get-vm | select VMName ReplicationMode, State | Where-Object  {(state -eq 'Running') -and (ReplicationMode -eq 'None')}
```

Is there a way to fix this without using "$_" syntax?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you like to avoid `$_`?

Comment: If you don't like `$_`, then use `$PSItem`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want to use `$_`?

`$_` represent each occurrence of your selection.

I did my own example. Where is the problem?

```
 Get-Process | select Id, ProcessName | Where-Object {($_.ProcessName -eq 'chrome') -and ($_.Id -gt 30000)}
```

Comment: I am under the assumption that "$_." is very old syntax from version 2.0 days and it will be deprecated soon. So, i am telling to find an alternative to it.

Comment: Some Documentation from MS (23/12/2019) still use it (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/scripting/samples/removing-objects-from-the-pipeline--where-object-?view=powershell-7). Where have you read $_ would be depreticated ?

Comment: from my manager actually LOL. Anyways thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: The new thing is to use $PSitem vs $_. It's been this way for a while now (since PowerShell v3 actually), but $_ and $PSItem virtually do the same thing and thus interchangeable and you'' see both used regularly.  As doc'd by MS here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/04/15/working-with-the-new-psitem-automatic-variable-in-windows-powershell-3-0/